# How to prevent integer reordering when converting to factor?

Tags: r

This is really more a question on the *why* and *how* of this behavior in R.

I have a vector

```
c("18", "68", "18-20", "22", "27", "16-18", "unkown")
```

I would expect that if I ran

```
as.factor(c("18", "68", "18-20", "22", "27", "16-18", "unkown"))
```

The levels would follow the order of the elements of the vector. Instead, they are ordered as if R tried to interpret the numeric characters in each element:

```
[1] 18     68     18-20  22     27     16-18  unkown
Levels: 16-18 18 18-20 22 27 68 unkown
```

I can see how this should happen if the elements were of class character, but practically integer/numeric. But because of more ambiguous formats such as `18-20`, I am not sure how R knows to order them.
In fact, if I had to transform to factor in two steps (first to integer, and then to factor):

```
> as.integer(c("18", "68", "18-20", "22", "27", "16-18", "unkown"))
[1] 18 68 NA 22 27 NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Which makes perfect sense because `18-20` is a simple character string.

Comment: Why is there a problem to you with this in first place? It makes more sense to display the levels after sorting it.

Comment: Much of this behavior is explained in `?factor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no set of levels is supplied, the documentation states that:

> levels:    an optional vector of the values (as character strings) that x
>   might have taken. The default is the unique set of values taken by
>   as.character(x), sorted into increasing order of x. Note that this set
>   can be specified as smaller than sort(unique(x)).

So it has nothing to do with the numeric values, they are sorted as if they were strings. And indeed:

```
> sort(unique(as.character(c("18", "68", "18-20", "22", "27", "16-18", "unkown"))))
[1] "16-18"  "18"     "18-20"  "22"     "27"     "68"     "unkown"
```

You can prevent the ordering as follows:

```
> x=c("18", "68", "18-20", "22", "27", "16-18", "unkown")
> factor(x,levels=unique(x))

[1] 18     68     18-20  22     27     16-18  unkown
Levels: 18 68 18-20 22 27 16-18 unkown
```